# How to handle commands that require user intervention when writing shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, automation

I am crating a script to deploy an application which requires me to install mysql.
now first command that i need to run is

```
apt install mysql-server
```

This has a y/n prompt which i can handle with -y flag
but after this i need to run the following command

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

This command asks user for multiple inputs like

```
validate password Y/n prompt, 
password strength 0/1/2, 
password, 
repeat password, 
continue with password y/n, 
delete anonymous users y/n, 
disallow remote root login y/n, 
remove test database y/n, 
reload previlidge tables y/n
```

Is there a way that i can specify all the options in the script

Comment: Assuming the command `mysql_secure_installation` is a script, check what it does and reimplement it in a non-interactive way.

Comment: Better scripts will already provide a way to override them. Read its source code -- if it's well-written it'll prompt the user only if the information isn't set by command-line arguments or environment variables. And if it _isn't_ well-written now, consider writing a patch to provide to the project that makes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a txt file with responses and pass it to your interactive command, like this:

```
/path/to/my/command << commands.txt
```

You can also use `expect` command: https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ and the bullet point regarding questions "that have been asked and answered many times before".